# Compiling two sets of C++ binaries under the same directory

Tags: c++

I have a directory called "feature/" under which all C++ files reside. Is it possible to compile two sets of binary files (say B1, B2), both sets under feature/, with each set compiled using two different machines M1 and M2? That is, B1 is generated using M1 and B2 is generated using M2.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I am working on M1 I should be able to load B1 and debug. Likewise, when I am working on M2, I load B2 and debug.

The problem I am facing is this: 
Assume M1 is a local machine, and M2 is a remote machine. M1 and M2 have different environments.
I am on a local machine M1 and I found a bug. I edit "feature/f1.cc", do an incremental recompile, and the bug is fixed. Next day I log on to M2. Since "feature/f1.cc" was edited, I will have to recompile. However, since I am on M2, the binaries that were compiled on M1 will no longer work on M2. Hence, I have to compile every file under "feature/" from scratch on M2. Compiling from scratch takes 1 hour. If I had two sets of binaries, one for each machine, then I could do incremental compilation which would take only 5 seconds.

Comment: With `CMake` generated solutions and out of source building I do builds like this. I have one source and more than 1 binary tree (with different settings and possibly different compiler / toolchanins) for the shared source tree.

Comment: Only share the source code not the binaries.

Comment: Consider reading up on version control systems such as [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Version control is definitely part of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different intermediary folders for .obj files or .o files, it will work, but it is the worst solution.
Version control will solve this problem nicely and CI will help you by compiling over night, running tests....